# Delete key from immutable object (redux state)

Tags: redux, immutability

I'm writing a redux reducer to delete a key from a state object:

```
state = {
  items: {
    key1: {foo: 'bar'},
    key2: {foo: 'baz'}
  },
  someOtherKey: 'value'
}
```

My reducer:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action=='DEL') {
    return {
      ...state,
      items: {
        ...state.items,
        [action.key]: undefined
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I expected that this would return a new state with the respective property deleted, but instead it returns a new state with the key still present in the object but having the value `undefined`.

Is there an elegant way in ES6 to write such a reducer? I guess I could use `Object.assign` and delete the property, but the above pattern is so much more expressive, so I'd like to write it this way if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using the lodash function `omit`:

```
import { omit } from 'lodash'

function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action=='DEL') {
    return {
      ...state,
      items: omit(state.items, action.key)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The fact that the lodash library contains such a function leads me to the assumption that there is probably no easier way to express the operation in simple JavaScript. If I'm wrong, let me know; I'd be very interested to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Untested, what about this? It will create a shallow copy (immutable) of each item, except the one you don't care for.

```
function reducer(state, action) {
    if (action == 'DEL') {
        return {
            ...state,
            items: Object.keys(state.items).reduce((obj, key) => {
                if (key !== action.key) {
                    obj[key] = { ...state.items[key]
                    }
                }
            }, {})
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without initialValue in the reduce function, the result type is the type of the item being reduced, in this case this would be the type of the key. To fix this, an empty object parameter should be added before the reduce closing brace -> }, {})

Answer (score 1):

Another technique: copy the object then delete the key:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  if (action=='DEL') {
    let newItems = {...state.items};  // Copy the object
    delete newItems[action.key];      // Remove key from the copy
    return {
      ...state,
      items: newItems,
    };
  }
}
```